# SWIFTUI - Catalyst app - How to set Document Types to show icon for file

Tags: swiftui, xcode11, catalyst

I use Xcode 11.4.1 and I want to show `GeoIcon.icns` icon for the file, with extension `.geo`, create with my simply app: `OpenSave`.
I have set `Document Types` and `Exported UTIs` as shown in the following screenshot.
[image]

The `Info.plist` file, deriving from the above settings, is the one shown in the screenshot below.
[image]

The result of the above settings is illustrated in the screen shown below.
[image]
Why do the files created by the Opensave app have the app's shrunken icon and not the one I set? What am I wrong in the `Document Types` and in the `Exported UTIs` setting?

I searched the web for several days, without finding any posts that would solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you use `.icns` as file type for the icons.

Have you tried a `.png` icon as well?

This should resolve your issue!

Comment: Unfortunately, the problem is not to replace the .icns file with a .jpg, because you need to use an .icns file for the icons, as indicated in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42089382/document-type-icon-not-showing-on-custom-file-macos) or [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19846128/how-do-i-access-images-for-document-icons-in-an-asset-catalog-in-the-xcode-5-p). I hope someone will explain to me how to find the solution.